# How do i use Regular expression in ng-pattern to avoid certain special character?

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have to avoid some some special characters in ng-pattern. I can able to avoid all special characters by using following code

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"
```

But I have to avoid only these charecters

```
%;:'",<>
```

How to do write ng-pattern

**Update:**

```
<input type="text" class="txt_box" ng-disabled="filechoosen" name="file_name" ng-pattern="/^[^%;:\x27\x22,<>{}[\]\/]*$/" ng-model="filenameedit" id="filenameedit">
<div style="color:Red"  ng-show="file_name.$error.pattern ">These charecters are not allowed</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
ng-pattern="/^[^%;:\x27\x22,<>{}[\]\/]*$/"
```

Note that `'` is turned to `\x27` and `"` to `\x22` to be used freely in an attribute value.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^` - start of the negated character class matching any chars other than...

  - `%;:\x27\x22,<>{}[\]\/` - `%`, `;`, `:`, `'`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]` and `/`
- `]*` - zero or more times
- `$` - end of string.

See the JS demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("angularApp", [])
.controller("myConfigGenCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.subnet = '';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myConfigGenCtrl">
  <div class="ipfield">
   <form  name="frm">
    <label class="plclabel">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="txt_box" ng-disabled="filechoosen" name="file_name" ng-pattern="/^[^%;:\x27\x22,<>{}[\]\/]*$/" ng-model="name" id="filenameedit">
    <div style="color:red" ng-show="frm.file_name.$error.pattern">Error: % ; : ' " &lt; &gt; { } [ ] and / are not allowed!</div>
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var no_spl_char = yourInput.replace(/[%;:'",<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
I have to do instead of this

Comment: @Vishnu What do you mean to say? You can't use `.replace()` in the `ng-pattern` attribute.

Comment: Yes I know that, I have used that code in jquery so i have avoid those characters in ng-pattern

Comment: @Vishnu So, use the `ng-pattern="/^[^%;:\x27\x22,<>]*$/"` and you won't need to replace those pesky chars ever again :)

Comment: ng-pattern="/^[^%;:\x27\x22,<>{}[]\/]*$/" is this correct i have added some more charecters

Comment: When adding `]` into the character class in JS regex, you must always escape it.

Comment: Thank you so much I have edited my code, I have used that pattern , If try to enter that characters am not getting the error message

Comment: Let me post a JS snippet. It would be better if you also posted a working snippet with your code.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/T7coSoIuETpKnELPvPtv?p=preview sorry check this one

Comment: @Vishnu You know, you have a typo in the controller name: `<body ng-contoller="myConfigGenCtr">` and `.controller("myConfigGenCtrl", function($scope)`?

Comment: @Vishnu See my updated answer. Note you should put the input into a form and fix some typos like `ng-contoller` to `ng-controller`.

Comment: Yes after put inside form it  works. Thank you so much

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can help me on this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888171/angular-text-box-avoid-only-1-special-character